# Best way to show a pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a page where upon clicking one of the links I am showing a pop-up.

To show that pop-up I am using a hidden div with an iframe in it to load the remote URL, and a JavaScript function to show it in the centre of the page.

What is the best alternative to this?

I want that the remote URL to be called by AJAX request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)
2. [Fancy Box](http://fancybox.net/)
3. [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)
4. [Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)
5. [Thickbox - outdated](http://thickbox.net/)

[Also Google in Stack Over Flow](https://www.google.com/search?q=using%20webrequest%20asp.net&oq=using%20webrequest%20asp.net&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%20stackoverflow.com%20jquery%20popup&oq=site%20stackoverflow.com%20jquery%20pop&gs_l=serp.3.0.33i21.749204.751124.6.752692.10.10.0.0.0.0.320.2634.2-9j1.10.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.756ksFfCRvI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=8d44242ae547b3f7&bpcl=38625945&biw=1280&bih=935)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use plugins for jQuery that help you to create and show popups in easy way. For example, [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox).
Check this examples: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

Answer (score 0):

I always use Pretty Photos Library which gives you the ability to open:

1. Photo Gallery
2. Flash
3. Content
4. Iframes
5. you tube videos
6. inline content
7. external websites

check it here: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/